# How Can I Remove Data in Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-calendar

I'm studying about a CustomCalendar.
I removed a event list in Recyclerview. But I can not remove data in calendar(Activity).
How can I touch this code?

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    MenuItem add = menu.add(Menu.NONE, 100,1,"수정");
    MenuItem remove = menu.add(Menu.NONE,101,2,"삭제");
    add.setOnMenuItemClickListener(onEditMenu);
    remove.setOnMenuItemClickListener(onEditMenu);
}

private final MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener onEditMenu = new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {


    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

            case 100 :
                Toast.makeText(context,"gd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;


            case 101 :
                arrayList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeRemoved(position,arrayList.size());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position,arrayList.size());
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: you need to notify your calender too about the changes

Comment: where does it show in your Activity?

Answer (score 0):

have you try adapter.notifydatasetchanged() after remove from the array